Expectation & Covariance matrix of indicator vector
Suppose we have the $p$-dimensional random vector $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)$. Take the set $A$ to be (without loss of generality) the negative real line, thus $A = (- \infty, 0)$. The indicator function $\mathbb{I}_A(\cdot)$ is defined so that $\mathbb{I}_A(\boldsymbol{X})$ is a $p$-dimensional binary vector with element $1 \leq j \leq p$ being defined as:
$$\mathbb{I}_A(\boldsymbol{X})_j = 0, \quad \text{if } X_j \in [0, \infty),$$
$$\mathbb{I}_A(\boldsymbol{X})_j = 1, \quad \text{if } X_j \in (-\infty, 0).$$
Say I am interested in the expectation and the covariance matrix of this vector. I know that for the univariate case, this all boils down to $\mathbb{P}(X_j < 0)$ but can I say that the expectation vector will be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{P}(X_1 < 0) & \ldots & \mathbb{P}(X_p < 0)\end{pmatrix}^\intercal?$$
What happens with the covariance matrix? I guess the diagonal elements are easy as these are just variances of Bernoulli variables with success probabilities equal to $\mathbb{P}(X_j < 0)$ for $j = 1, \ldots, p$ but what about the covariances?

The expectation vector you have is correct. Now use the standard formula for the covariance and write the expression in terms of probabilities of the $X_i$ and $X_j$.
